# How to play an audio from internet in flutter?

Tags: audio, flutter

I am making an online radio app. So, i want to it on my phone using an app build with flutter.
I tried some plugins, but didn't work for me.
Please can someone tell me how can i do it?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: @rstrelba Thank you.... I will try.